# RegEx optional part

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract an artist and song title from strings such as these:

```
Some Guy - Cool Song
Some Guy - Cool Song [FooBar Release]
```

I want to get these groups:

```
Some Guy
Cool Song
```

I do not care about the `[FooBar Release]` part.

I came up with the following RegEx:

```
(.*?)(?:\s*-\s*)(.*)(?:\s*\[.*\])?
```

This works on the first string, but on the second string group 2 takes up everything after the `-`, so I get `Cool Song [FooBar Release]`.

[regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/dK9dJ9)

Comment: Make your second subpattern ungreedy: `(.*)` -> `(.*?)` (you might need to anchor the whole pattern with a `$` too)

Comment: @cmbuckley I didn't think of anchoring the pattern with `$`. Along with making group 2 ungreedy, I got it to work the way I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to not only make the second subgroup lazy, but also anchor the whole thing with `$`:

```
(.*?)(?:\s*-\s*)(.*?)(?:\s*\[.*\])?$
```

This gives me the following subgroups:

```
Some Guy
Cool Song
```

The part in square brackets is completely ignored in the subgroups.

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/zB2bO2)

Answer (score 1):

If you can trim the whitespace on your string after the capture, this becomes much simpler.

```
([^-]*)\-([^[]*)
```

This will result in

```
(Some Guy )-( Cool Song )[FooBar Release]
```